# Matplotlib How to get length line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use `Matplotlib` with Python 2.7.6 and my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import spline


x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([1,5,15])

x_smooth = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
y_smooth = spline(x, y, x_smooth)
plt.plot(x_smooth, y_smooth)
plt.show()
```

When I run it show [image](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-EqXGr8Bh6aU/VTXRBwgoA1I/AAAAAAAAFGo/1cgESEkaJYk/s1600/Screenshot%2Bfrom%2B2015-04-21%2B11%3A21%3A33.png)

How to get the length of `Spline` ? Help me

Comment: What do you mean length? Simply len(y_smooth) gives you the array length, which of course is 100.

Comment: @NathanGeorge I assume just the length of the actual line.

Comment: ah right, the length of the line path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import math
distance = 0
for count in range(1,len(y_smooth)):
    distance += math.sqrt(math.pow(x_smooth[count]-x_smooth[count-1],2) + math.pow(y_smooth[count]-y_smooth[count-1],2))
```

in cartesian geometry the distance between two points is calculated as

p1(x,y), p2(a,b)

[p1p2] = sqrt((a-x)^2 + (b-y)^2)

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this, probably in a one-liner

Comment: I understand your way, you split spline to multiple lines, applied **Pytago** to calculate the length of each line segment, then sum all length. But, there is no simple ways?

Comment: yep, I also use this way to solve the problem, but I would expect a utility function is available from Matplotlib more :D Thank you

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure of a matplotlib function, maybe a numpy, pandas, or scipy function exists for it.  You could also do it with reduce somehow, although I haven't quite got it

f = lambda x2, x1, y2, y1 : math.sqrt(math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + math.pow(y2 - y1, 2))
print reduce(f, zip(x_smooth, y_smooth), 0)